# "is" or "play" for a role?

Tags: collocation

i heard someone say "Music is such an important role in my life." I have always thought "role" should be used with "play / have / take", so it goes like "Music has an important role in my life." Is it possible to say like the first sentence?

Comment: In slurred speech, *music has* is easy to mistake for *music is*.

Comment: @RegDwight: I think even in non-slurred American speech, there are lots of people who pronounce *music has* almost exactly the same way as *music is*. I (and lots of other people) would drop the *'h'*. I *think* I pronounce the reduced vowels of *is* and *has* differently, but not very differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the phasing & context. Your example sounds a bit off:

> Music is such an important role in my life.

To my ears *has* sounds more appropriate:

> Music has such an important role in my life.

But a more colloquial way of expressing the concept is via the word *plays*:

> Music plays such an important role in my life.

Or even:

> Music takes such an important role in my life.

Comment: Thank you. I also have felt the same way. I'll use HAS. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not convinced that 'role' is the best word to use here. Were it me I would say 'Music plays an important part in my life'. 'Role' is not wrong, but for 'part' is certainly the more usual idiom.